# Security group rule between aws external ALB and privale Ip ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-elb

I have created external application load balancer in aws, i need to wirite security group rule to allow traffic from only one private subnet ec2-instance. any suggestions please ?

Comment: First of all, make sure you are placing the ELB in Availability Zones where your subnet(s) can be addressed within your VPC. Then use Security Groups (SG) with relevant ports and SG source whitelisted along with other configs for NACLs and Routing tables configured correctly.

Comment: @ashan Thanks for reply, i have placed ELB and ec2 instance in sampe vpc same AZ but diffrent subnets, ec2 in private subnet ELB in public subnet why because it;s internet facing load balancer , can you suggest me in this case how can i configure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private subnet

If a subnet's default traffic is routed to a NAT instance/gateway or completely lacks a default route, the subnet is known as a private subnet. For example, an instance launched in this subnet is not publicly accessible even if it has an Elastic IP address or a public IP address associated with it.

Open your VPC nat IP in ELB security group

Answer (score 0):

I found answer myself, after a lot digging into aws doc's , here i have to allow nat ip in security rules of ELB